# How to access the name of the last method called in the current scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to get a list of the methods called in the current scope, for example within another method?

I know that I can get information about the method currently being executed, but is it possible to do it for the one whose execution just ended?

```
def my_method
  [1, 3, 2].sort

  # is there a magic method that does this?
  last_method_called = magic_method
  # last_method_called is now :sort
end
```

My intention is to add a type of a logger to my models and controllers, and to free the method code of as much clutter as possible. After I call some method, for example this `sort` on an array, right after it I would like to have access to:

- current method
- current class/module
- last method called

These I would pass to my logging method, which would use that info to generate some log message. For example, I could keep the message text in localization yaml files, where keys correspond to classes, methods and last methods.

I need this kind of logging for rake tasks, data migrations, etc, and I want to avoid this:

```
output = "Seeding pages:\n"
pages.each |page|
  output << "  * #{page.label}\n"
  status = page.do_something
  output << "    did something to the page: #{status}"
end
```

(Please note, this above is just an improvisation to make a point)

Instead of that, it would be nice if I could have something like this:

```
# ...
status = page.do_something
log status
```

Where log is a method added to the class via concern, and that would do something like this:

```
def log(message)
  # current_method - a helper that I would add, returns Symbol
  # current_class - a helper that I would add, returns Symbol
  # last_method - a helper that I would add, returns Symbol
  @log << I18n.t last_method, scope: [current_class, current_method], message: message
end
```

Comment: No, it is not possible (besides parsing the output of `source_location` of `__callee__`.)

Comment: Why do you need this capability? May be there are better ways to solve the problem for which you think this is solution.  FYI: `Array#sort` is C method.  You can play with Ruby's `TracePoint` class, but it may not help you to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I will update the question with explanation what I intend with this.
Btw, sort is also a valid ruby array function: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort

Comment: I meant `Array#sort` is implemented in `C`, so if you were using `TracePoint`, you will have to use event `:c_call` to record that it was called.  In Ruby, there is a way to find current class (`self.class`) and current method (`__method__`) - last method called seems impossible to find out.

Comment: You don't want to store the full backlog of all method calls in memory. That could kill your process in no time.

Comment: @theTinMan: You could (maybe) do something like this though: set a trace func (`set_trace_func`) and capture only methods that are called in a scope indicated as being of interest. Keep a single variable of the last method called from that scope, and return that. Hmm.

Comment: Yes, something that selectively cherry-picked method-calls of interest could survive, but it'd be an iterative process narrowing it down, with the dead bodies of processes that didn't survive being left on the ground. Kind of like using a debugger to figure out why code is misbehaving. "I'll just step over this method... DOH!" :-)